# Cursor missing after typeheadOnSelect

Tags: javascript, angular, typehead

I have a text box with `[typehead]` attribute, on the event `(typeheadonSelect)`, once the value is selected from the drop-down list.

The issue is cursor disappears once the user selects an item from the list, the item displays on the `textbox` but the cursor disappears.

I want the cursor to appear back on the text box. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: can u show us the code...what have u tried??

Answer (score 0):

You can add following style within your tag to generate cursor back.

```
style="cursor: pointer"
```

eg:

```
<input type="text" style="cursor: pointer"/>
```